# ¿Como trabajar con métodos asíncronos y visualizar las resultados en la vista en Ionic u otro?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic, async

Estoy aprendiendo como usar estos métodos pero al momento de consumir una APi que tengo en Laravel o suponiendo que este en cualquier lado aveces demora en devolver los resultados y al cargar la vista o pagina no se muestran los resultados, simplemente se ve en blanco.

Ejemplo un método en la forma que consumi un APi.Como verán en el me cree un archivo api-rest-service.ts donde coloco todas las rutas que voy consumiendo

```
getRegistros(datos){
    return this.http.post(`https://mipagina.com/historial-registros`,datos);
  }
```

Luego con el suscribe trato de obtener los datos:

```
 this.service.getRegistros(datos)
              .subscribe(result => {
                    this.arrayRegistros = result['registros']
              }
  });
```

Y con este ultimo almaceno los datos en una varaible, funciona perfectamente cuando le paso un console.log, pero al querer visualizar en  una vista aveces se visualiza y aveces no, intente usando e importando la el loadig

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

y dentro del subscribe hacer el loading.dismiss(); pero aun asi obtengo los mismos resultados, alguien sabra la manera correcta para esperar los datos y luego visualizar los registros en la vista?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega tu vista y todos los componentes que sean necesarios para reproducir tu caso :D

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada estoy asumiento que usas Ionic con angular, para darte esta respuesta.

Al usar Observables, es recomendable y buena practica usar la pipa **async** dentro de la view del componente/directiva al momento de mostrar el ***arrayRegistros*** , te recomiendo esta opcion porque es parte de lo que hoy en dia se conoce como *Programacion Reactiva*

Te dejo esta documentacion [Angular / AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) que es de muy buena ayuda.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos,

Comment: he usado el asycn pero aun me queda muchas dudas al usarlo

Comment: @LuisHernandez Si, comprendo. te recomiendo que repases estos conceptos, que los describen en los siguientes links y se que te sacan de muchas duda, leelos en el orden que te los envio:

1.- https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-teorica-observables-angular.html

2.- https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-async-pipe-angular

Si aun tiene mas dudas, puedes enviarme un mensaje privado.


Recuerda marcar mi respuesta como util si te ha servido,

Saludos,